# Proof that a linear operator T on a finite-dimensional vector space V is diagonalizable iff V is the direct sum of the eigenspaces of T

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, direct-sum

I am studying diagonalizability right now and I'm having trouble understanding [this theorem](https://www.math.uh.edu/~jiwenhe/math4377/lectures/sec5_2.pdf) (5.11, last page).

> A linear operator T on finite-dimensional vector space V is
>   diagonalizable if and only if V is the direct sum of the eigenspaces
>   of T.

I know that a linear transformation $T$ is diagonalizable iff there exists subspaces $v_i,...v_k$ such that

(i) $V = V_1 \oplus ... \oplus V_k$

(ii) for every $1\leq i \leq k$, the subspace $V_i$ is T-invariant. That is, $T(v_i) \leq V_i$

(iii) $T$ (restricted on $v_i$) $= \lambda_i$ Id$_{v_i}$. That is, for each $v \in V$, we have $T(v) = \lambda_i v$

Also, $T$ is diagonalizable if there exists a basis $B$ of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors for $T$. That is, for each $v \in B$ there exists a scalar $\lambda$ such that $T(v) = \lambda v$

---

But how do we conclude,

$T$ is diagonalizable $\iff \oplus{V_ \lambda }$ where $\lambda\in Spec(T)$

In the theorem above?

Comment: Your (iii) states that $V_i$ is an eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_i$. Your (i) states that $V$ is a direct sum of those eigenspaces. What exactly is left to prove?

Comment: If $V$ is the direct sum of eigenspaces, find a basis for each eigenspace, then put all those bases together to get a basis for $V$ consisting of eigenvectors (any nonzero vector in an eigenspace is an eigenvectgors). If $T$ is diagonalizable, show the eigenspaces are spanned by the elements of a diagonalizing basis $\beta$ corresponding to that eigenvalue, and that their sum is direct and exhausts $V$.